# Rails: How to make role groups using rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I am new to rolify. I tried to use it together with Cancancan.
 
For now, if I want to grant a user permissions to create and update, I need to add_role twice.

```
user.add_role :moderator, Forum
user.add_role :creator, Forum
```

Here the problem is that one role can only have one permission, 
I want to add role like this, `user.add_role :creator,moderator, Forum`

If this is not possible,I want to build role_groups, a user can have multiple role_groups, a role_group can have multiple roles

Answer (score 0):

Rolify just creates roles. But to assign them powers or ability like create or moderate you can use cancan gem. In cancan there is file named as ability. Where you can assign ability to different roles. I have given an example below.

```
if user.has_role? :moderator
      can :manage, [
          News,
          Event,
          Headline,
          Blog,
          Testimonial,
          CourseList,
          Chat,
          ComplaintType,
          Complaint,
          Download,
          Faculty,
          Gallery,
          Headline,
          Infrastructure,
          Leed,
          Notice,
          Press,
          Profile,
          Query,
          User,
          Newspaper
      ]
    end

    can :read, [
        Blog,
        Download,
        Event,
        Faculty,
        Gallery,
        Headline,
        Infrastructure,
        Press,
        Testimonial,
        CourseList
    ]
    can :create, [
        Leed,
        Query
    ]
```

Comment: hi, I am using cancancan. I just hope to enable user to choose role_group which is made of multiple roles

Comment: There is only one way to do that by creating another role and giving it ability of both creator and moderator. Like in my answer I have given moderator ability to manage, read and create.